# How to get element by attribute name which ends with defined word

Tags: xpath

In my XML I have elements

```
<driverConfig name="ADriver">
    ...
            </driverConfig>

            <driverConfig name="BDriver">
    ...
            </driverConfig>
```

Is there a way how to select all value of sub-element. Problem is I can modify just first name in this expression which I already tried but with no success:

```
//driverConfig[@name="*Driver"]/fd:properties/fd:property[@name="path"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With XPath 2.0 you can do `//driverConfig[ends-with(@name, 'Driver')]/fd:properties/fd:property[@name="path"]` respectively `//driverConfig[matches(@name, 'Driver$')]/fd:properties/fd:property[@name="path"]`.

With XPath 1.0 you can use `//driverConfig[substring(@name, string-length(@name) - 5) = 'Driver']/fd:properties/fd:property[@name="path"]`.

Comment: hm that is nice but as I said I can change just this part *Driver because I am usin 3rd part libraries called faban and tthere is always this part //driverConfig[@name=".."]

Comment: @hudi: If that's the only thing you can change, then there is no way to do what you're asking.